# Working with varied slope impacts for a cost surface

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I'm working in ArcMap and trying to create a Cost surface for movement through a terrain. I have values (speed in km/hr) for each surface type (tarmac, grass, forest etc).

The problem is moving into the 3rd dimension, z values and slope, created from a DEM dataset. The issue is that the impact which slope has on speed is different moving up slope (every 1% slows by 0.65km/hr) to moving down slope (every 1% increases speed by 0.35km/hr).

Has anyone come across an easy way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181592/possible-point-location-algorithm/182618#182618 this is all doable on rasters using Path Distance and vertical factor parameters

Comment: My goal is to calculate the optimum route between point A and point B, both defined within the system. So perhaps a direction function is important to suggest which way to move over the slope? I like how you add in Toblers function but was this added through python?

Comment: Very little python in there, and as I said approach is directly applicable to your case

Comment: Thanks for the help @FelixIP, just trying to get the concept straight in my head. This method would work with a 3rd component or just 2? Assuming that moving horizontally across a slope is a different impact on speed when compared to up or down slope?

Comment: It works with 3D, because vertical factor takes direction into account, there is a lookup table OPTION where your represent your slopes (degrees!) vs factor, i.e. start from negative go through zero to positives. A bit tricky and naughty but works

Comment: @FelixIP, I have my Cost surface and my slope raster (as a percentage) but i dont understand how you can get the system to run with a different value for up or downhill. 1% increase in gradient uphill slows by 0.65km/hr while a 1% decrease in gradient increases speed by 0.35km/hr and across slope slows by 0.15km/hr per 1% gradient. Can you explain?

Comment: What on earth is across the slope? How is this different to horizontal?

Comment: The speed which you can move on a perfectly flat surface is different to that which you can move horizontally across a steep slope. There is no vertical displacement so it seems flat but it has a negative effect on moving speed. Id be happy if i could understand how to calculate it based on the uphill or downhill variables though and get a working model.

Comment: Did someone delete the comment below by @FelixIP?