# Navigating Outdoor Area with obstacles

Tags: arcpy, postgis, geoserver, openstreetmap, osm2po

I am trying to navigate in an outdoor area from one point to the other, e.g. in an area with hills or mountains, and I would like to declare a hill as an obstacle if the change in elevation is too large relative to the distance. What tools would be best to use to work through this problem, and from what sources I can get DEM data for this purpose. (e.g. Scottish Highlands)

I would like to consider an area of 100 metre radius at a time for the purpose of obstacle identification and avoidance.

Can the hills (Obstacles) be avoided from the gradient descent threshold?

I am new to GIS and don't know much about it.

Comment: GIS can do this kind of thing but it's too complex an issue to lay out in a focused Q&A format such as this site. In ArcGIS, I'd look at the Least Cost Path tool, that might do what you need.

Comment: your question is a bit general for this site, but before people vote to close it I will advise to research DEM(digital elevation model) raster data. from there you can generate trails based on elevation, slope, aspect and mask out your obvious obstacles like bodies of water

Comment: @ziggy can you please also suggest that if I extract an image from OpenStreetMap can I navigate that outdoor area by avoiding obstacles. (I want to write a code for this problem, any tool you can suggest in this regard?).

Comment: I fairly certain you cannot use an image for the analysis you want to do. have you done any research on this topic? have you seen examples that its possible?

Comment: you really need lidar data and or a DEM

Comment: Well I have done some research on Unknown Graph Exploration techniques, and if image input won't be of any use, can I get graph data for the maps and analyse the problem in hand? By considering the nodes present in the map and traversing from one to the other.

Comment: @ziggy can you please suggest me the tools that I can use to find out the elevations in DEM data?

Comment: elevation values are part of a DEM (hence Digital Elevation Model)

Comment: check out this question: my answer (is more relevant to your case then the question I answered it for) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241330/arcgis-tools-for-hiking-distance-calculations/241341#241341